# Proof of RSA Public-Key Encryption Theorem

Tags: rsa, public-key-encryption

Un, for any positive integer n, is the multiplicative group modulo n, consisting of
these positive integers that are relatively prime to n (equivalently, they have multiplicative inverses
modulo n).

Prove that if n = pq for two distinct primes p and q, then the order of Un is ((p-1)(q-1))

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you show us what have you tried to solve this problem? What is the problem that you're having? StackOverflow exists to help you solve problems, not to do all your work for you. :)

Comment: This isn't a programming question.  It would probably get better responses at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is really a math question that can also be asked on our crypto site and because absolutely no effort has been demonstrated.